# Stacking two DIVs with float: right

Tags: css, css-float, overlap

Hihi, I am trying to create a slide down menu using DIV, but hit a problem that I can't really figure out how to overcome. Let's take a look at the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>test</title> 
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu").click(function () {
                $('#menuItem').slideDown('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 10px;">
        <div id="menuItem" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
            MenuItem1<br />
            MenuItem2<br />
            MenuItem3<br />
            MenuItem4<br />
            MenuItem5<br />
            MenuItem6<br />
            MenuItem7
        </div>
        <div id="menu" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right; cursor: pointer;">
            My Menu
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 50px 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;">
        <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; height: 500px;">
            <div style=" position: relative; z-index: 1; float: right;">Form Element</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want to achieve is to make my slide down menu stay on top of my form element div. Please advice how can this be done. Many thanks!

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty: I added an absolutely-positioned outer containing  for the menu, and then applied `top:40px` to the content `div` to push it down to compensate for the height of the menu.

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;">
    <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 10px; ">
        <div id="menuItem" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right;  display: none; cursor: pointer;">
            MenuItem1<br />
            MenuItem2<br />
            MenuItem3<br />
            MenuItem4<br />
            MenuItem5<br />
            MenuItem6<br />
            MenuItem7
        </div>
        <div id="menu" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right; cursor: pointer;">
            My Menu
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div style="margin: 50px 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;  position:relative; top:40px; ">
        <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; height: 500px;">
            <div style=" clear:both;  z-index: 1; float: right;">Form Element</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I type this, dotty's already answered before me with a pretty much identical approach. However, in the code above, the individual menu `div`s are properly floating next to each other as you want them to, as they do in the first code you posted in the question.

There are probably some `div` and styling elements that are a little redundant there now.

Edit: It does occur to me now that the operation of the menu in dotty's code is actually probably how you *intended* for the menu to be.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, adding a absolute outer container does the trick for my menu nicely!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the #menuItem div inside the #menu div, and set the #menuItem div's position to absolute and remove it's float.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>test</title> 

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menu").click(function () {
            $('#menuItem').slideDown('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 10px;">

    <div id="menu" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: relative; z-index: 10; float: right; cursor: pointer;">
        My Menu

        <div id="menuItem" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; z-index: 10; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
            MenuItem1<br />
            MenuItem2<br />
            MenuItem3<br />
            MenuItem4<br />
            MenuItem5<br />
            MenuItem6<br />
            MenuItem7
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div style="margin: 50px 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;">
    <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; height: 500px;">
        <div style=" position: relative; z-index: 1; float: right;">Form Element</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I have adopted Trev16v suggestion. :)